# Yii2 AR left join with where and relations

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Book

```
----------------------------
| id  |  name |  published |
----------------------------
|  1  | book1 |     1      |
|  2  | book2 |     1      |
|  3  | book3 |     0      |
```

Chapter

```
----------------------------
| id  |  book_id |   name   | published |
----------------------------
|  1  |    1     | chapter1 |     1      |
|  2  |    1     | chapter2 |     0      |
|  2  |    2     | chapter1 |     0      |
|  3  |    3     | chapter1 |     1      |

class Book{
    public function getChapter()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Chapter::className(), ['kook_id' => 'id']);
    } }

class Chapter{
    public function getBook()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Book::className(), ['id' => 'book_id']);
    } }
```

How can i get published books with published pages using ActiveRecord (i want get book1 with chapter1 and book2 without any chapters)?

smth like Book::find($id)->where(['published' => 1])->  {{{left join with where}}}   ->all())

ADDED
And then i wand to use it

```
echo $book->name;
foreach($book->getChapter() as chapter){
    echo chapter->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Book class `relation` as

```
class Book
{
   public function getChapter()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(Chapter::className(), ['book_id' => 'id'])->where(['published' => 1]);
   }
}
```

To get Related Records use `with()`

```
Book::find()->with(['chapter'])->where(['id' => $id ,'published' => 1])->all()
```

To Use it:

```
  //Book Name
  echo $book->name;

  //For Chapters Name
  if($book->chapter){
  foreach($book->chapter as $chapter){
    echo $chapter->name;
   }
}
```

Comment: And how to use it (look my question was added)?